# how to get specific part from string in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I want to retrieve file names from urls in sql.
for example:

Input:

url:

https://www.google.co.in/root/subdir/file.extension?p1=v1&p2=v2
https://www.abxdhcak.com/sitemap-companies.xml

then Output should be:

file.extension

sitemap-companies.xml

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried, what didn't work?

Comment: SUBSTRING(string_expression, CHARINDEX(expression_to_find, string_expression).... i know this code..but i'm confused that what should i put for 'expression_to_find' as '/' opccurs so many time....

Comment: oracle REGEXP functions may help, but i think you need a little more complicated processing if you want to recognize a lot of pattern from a given url. what would be the url list? is it fixed or can be anything? how sould the program know the sitemap-companies.xml will be the output? and what if there is a plus page in the url: https://www.abxdhcak.com/sitemap/companies/sitemap-companies.xml

Comment: Is the file.extension always at the end of the string?

Comment: Are your URLs in a column?  What tools are you using to do the SQL?  PL/SQL, SQLPlus? Toad?

Comment: yes...URls are in column...and i'm using sql..

Comment: it's not necessary that file.extension will be at the end of string

Answer (score 0):

To match your expected output you can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm#i1305521)

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '^.*/|\?.*$') as rg
```

This does 2 things:

```
'^.*/'
```

This removes all characters up to and including the last forward-slash in the string.

```
'\?.*$'
```

This removes all characters after and including a question mark.

This may not work for all cases, but it works for the examples provided.

Comment: Thank you.. it seems that it is very difficult to write query because of randomness in input..